# Working with futures in slick and scalatra

Tags: scala, slick, scalatra

I am trying to handle a future I got from slick in order to generate a response to a request, but I'm stuck at the "async" part.

Here is a snippet:

```
get("/tmp") {
  new AsyncResult() {
    override val is: Future[_] = db.run(Users.findUserWithLogin("user"))
  }
}
```

Now, the db.run call returns a Future[Option[User]]. How do I returns a response depending on the content of the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to map the future returned by Slick to the result that you want rather than setting `is` directly to the Slick result. So, the following would be an example of how you might handle it:

```
get("/tmp") {
  new AsyncResult() {
    val is = db.run(Users.findUserWithLogin("user")) map {
      case Some(u) => //return some stuff about the user
      case None => //return some stuff about user not being found
    }
  }
}
```

As noted in the comments below, the `AsyncResult` is not strictly necessary. You can find more details in the [Scalatra documentation](http://scalatra.org//guides/2.6/async/akka.html).

Comment: This, and the `AsyncResult` is not [strictly necessary](http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/async/akka.html#toc_173).

Comment: @Esardes Thanks for the comment. I will edit the answer to add.